# Использование MS SQL и PostgreSQL в одном приложении

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Требуется считывать данные из БД MS SQL и записывать в PostgreSQL. Возможно ли реализовать подобное при помощи EF CORE. Подключение к обоим БД (считывание\запись) выполняется успешно, но это в консольных приложениях созданных для каждой БД. А как в одном приложении считывать с MS SQL и записывать в PostgreSQL не совсем представляю. Если такое возможно, напишите, пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.

Comment: По-видимому, нужно открыть несколько разных подключений и использовать их

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Как объяснить, EF Core что в данном случае следует использовать подключение MS SQL, а в другом PostgreSQL?

Comment: У Вас должен быть класс, наследующийся от DbContext, который переопределяет метод `OnConfiguring`, где прописывается строка подключения, например, для SqlServer'а так ` optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");` Так вот, создаёте аналогичный второй класс, где подключаетесь уже к PostgreSQL БД. И используете два инстанса двух разных классов для взаимодействия с ними.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, все получилось. Для создания классов в консоли указывал: для MS SQL PM> Scaffold-DbContext "server=xxx\INFSERVER;database=SQL_USERS;User ID=sa;Password=123456" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. Для PostgreSQL Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Users;Username=postgres;Password=1234" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. Получились два разных  контекста, с переопределенными метода OnConfiguring

Comment: Я рад, тогда оформлю как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно открыть несколько разных подключений и использовать их.
У Вас должен быть класс, наследующийся от DbContext, который переопределяет метод OnConfiguring, где прописывается строка подключения, например, для SqlServer'а так
`optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");`
Так вот, создаёте аналогичный второй класс, где подключаетесь уже к PostgreSQL БД. И используете два инстанса двух разных классов для взаимодействия с ними.